# Inequality involving $|\cos(x)|$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

If we have:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{N}|\cos(\omega x_k)|=1$$
then, how can the following inequality:
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{N-1+|\cos(\omega x_k)|}\le1$$
be proven?
Thanks:

Comment: Are $\omega$ and $x_k$ supposed to be real, or arbitrary complex numbers?

Comment: @DanielFischer: $x_k$ and $\omega$ are real numbers.

Comment: In that case, the only way to have the product equal $1$ is if $\cos \omega x_k = \pm 1$ for all $k$, and that simplifies the sum greatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{N}|\cos(\omega x_k)|=1 \implies |\cos(\omega x_k)|=1$$
so this is really an equality.

Comment: **facepalm** =D